# How to find most occuring records in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table of Employees full names and I need to retrieve the most occurring name associated with the frequency of it, regardless it was first or sec or third..etc. the intended result is to be like the second table

```html
  <br><br>
    <table>

      <tr>
        <th>ID </th>
        <th>FirstName</th>
        <th>SecName</th>
        <th>ThirdName</th>
        <th>ForthName</th>
        <th>SixName</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Sam</td>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Mark</td>
        <td>Thomas</td>
        <td>William</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Peter</td>
        <td>Wolf</td>
        <td>Sam</td>
        <td>Philip</td>
        <td>Sam</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Mark</td>
        <td>Black</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
        <td>Luke</td>
        <td>Johnny
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br> 
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Name </th>
        <th>Frq</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Sam</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mark</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td> John</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

etc then the rest of the names that are having the same frquency

Comment: This is unusual schema design... and not in a good way.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select Name,count(1) Frq from (
  select `FirstName` Name
  from T
  union all
  select `SecName` Name
  from T
  union all
  select `ThirdName` Name
  from T
  union all
  select `ForthName` Name
  from T
  union all
  select `SixName` Name
  from T
) AllT
group by Name
order by count(1) desc
```

---

**TESTDDL**

```
CREATE TABLE T
    (`ID` int, `FirstName` varchar(5), `SecName` varchar(5), `ThirdName` varchar(5), `ForthName` varchar(6), `SixName` varchar(7))
;

INSERT INTO T
    (`ID`, `FirstName`, `SecName`, `ThirdName`, `ForthName`, `SixName`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Sam', 'John', 'Mark', 'Thomas', 'William'),
    (2, 'Peter', 'Wolf', 'Sam', 'Philip', 'Sam'),
    (3, 'Mark', 'Black', 'Smith', 'Luke', 'Johnny')
;
```

---

**Result:**

```
|    Name | count(1) |
|---------|----------|
|     Sam |        3 |
|    Mark |        2 |
|   Smith |        1 |
| William |        1 |
|   Peter |        1 |
|  Thomas |        1 |
|  Johnny |        1 |
|  Philip |        1 |
|    John |        1 |
|    Luke |        1 |
|    Wolf |        1 |
|   Black |        1 |
```

---

### [TEST DEMO LINK](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/510275/4/0)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `union all` and `group by`:

```
select n.name, count(*)
from ((select FirstName as name from t) union all
      (select SecName as name from t) union all
      (select ThirdName as name from t) union all
      (select FourthName as name from t) union all
      (select SixthName as name from t) 
     ) n
group by n.name
order by count(*) desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```